# Como limitar palavras PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, gostaria de saber como eu limito o texto que eu puxo do banco de dados.

**Por exemplo, eu tenho um texto chamado:**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

**E queria que limitasse o texto ao puxar, ficaria tipo:**

Lorem ipsum dol...

```
<?php $row['title']; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de uma maneira simples:

```
echo substr($row['title'],0,26).'...'; ?>
```

Com método:

```
function limitChars($text, $limit=20)
{
  return substr($text, $limit).'...';
}
echo limitChars($row['title'], 26);
```

Ou, com método sem quebrar palavras; considere que toda string no PHP é um array, basta quebrá-lo nos espaços:

```
function limitChars($text, $limit=4)
{
 $join = array();
 $ArrayString = explode(" ", $text);

    if ($limit > count($ArrayString)) {
        $limit = count($ArrayString) / 2;   
    }

    foreach ($ArrayString as $key => $word) {
              $join[] = $word;
           if ($key == $limit) {
               break;
         }
    }
    //print_r($join);
    return implode(" ", $join)."...";

}
echo limitChars($row['title'], 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simples imprementação por quantidade fixa de caracteres:**

```
$texto= strip_tags($texto);

if (strlen($texto) > 500) {

    // Limitando string
    $corteTexto= substr($texto, 0, 500);

    //certifique-se que termina em uma palavra...
    $texto= substr($corteTexto, 0, strrpos($corteTexto, ' ')).'...'; 
}
echo $texto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `substr()` e fazer algo assim:

```
<?php
    $variavel = substr($row['title'], 0, -5))
?>

<spam title="<= $row['title']; ?>"><= $variavel ?>...</span>
```

`substr("texto a ser limitado", onde inicia, onde termina)`

Exps:

```
substr("texto a ser limitado", 0, -5)
Saida: texto a ser lim
substr("texto a ser limitado", 5, -2)
Saida:  a ser limita
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solução no `PHP`

Utilize o [`substr`](http://php.net/substr)

Exemplo, limitando até 15 letras:

```
$title = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
echo substr($title, 0, 15) . '...';
```

> Lorem ipsum dol...

### [Exemplo IdeOne](http://ideone.com/cmNH42)

No seu caso faria algo assim:

```
<?php echo substr($row['title'], 0, 15) . '...'; ?>
```

---

### Solução no `MySQL`

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(valor, 1, 15), '...') as valor
FROM teste
```

### [Exemplo SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5fe6/12/0)